# Scratch Org Case Language field is not presented

Tags: salesforcedx

I want to have the Case Language field in a scratch org. Base on the documentation it would be present with the service cloud.

> The language of the case. This field is available in all Enterprise,
> Performance, and Unlimited orgs with the Service Cloud. Out of the
> box, it's used only by Einstein Case Classification.

I am creating a scratch org with the following config below **but** still, the `Case Language` field is still not presented in the scratch org.

```
{
    "orgName": "Winer Linien",
    "edition": "Enterprise",
    "country": "AT",
    "language": "de",
    "features": [
        "ForceComPlatform",
        "StateAndCountryPicklist",
        "DefaultWorkflowUser",
        "MultiCurrency",
        "PersonAccounts",
        "ServiceCloud",
        "ServiceUser",
        "CPQ",
        "Communities",
        "Knowledge",
        "LiveAgent",
        "LightningServiceConsole",
        "LiveMessage"
      ],
    "settings": {
        "lightningExperienceSettings": {
            "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
        },
        "pathAssistantSettings": {
            "pathAssistantEnabled": true
        },
        "chatterSettings": {
            "enableChatter": true
        },
        "enhancedNotesSettings": {
            "enableEnhancedNotes": true
        },
        "languageSettings": {
            "enableTranslationWorkbench":  true,
            "enableEndUserLanguages": true
        },
        "omniChannelSettings": {
            "enableOmniChannel": true
        },
        "liveAgentSettings": {
          "enableLiveAgent": true
        }
    }
}
```

Do you know how we can achieve to activate the Case Language field in scratch org?

Comment: Try adding `CaseClassification` on features list.